# Play background Youtube video in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am playing a YouTube video with videoId in background.

How can I play it in loop?

```
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cvteffects/vscript.js"></script>
$('#background-video').YTPlayer({
        fitToBackground: true,
        videoId: 'J0_nASX8cvs',
        startSeconds: 15,
        pauseOnScroll: false,
        repeat: true,
        loop: true,
        autoPlay: true
        //callback: function() {
          //var player = $('#background-video').data('ytPlayer').player;
          //console.log("callback", player);
        //}
      });
    });
```

This is what I am doing. But video is not playing in loop.

Need help.

Comment: It seems to work https://jsfiddle.net/gfjukfoe/ I cant find option `videoId` in docs. May be you need to use `videoURL` instead?

Comment: Thanks Narek-T, but this is now my solution.

Comment: maybe you can add your youtube video to an iframe, which have css option display:none, I think it would be a trick :)

Comment: or another solution is to catch stop event of youtube video, and replay it manually. It can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580388/youtube-embedded-video-start-stop-event

Comment: Thanks for the options, I am using iframe API to get the src.

Answer (score 1):

Try Something like this

```
<div style="display:none">
    <iframe width="420" height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/oHg5SJYRHA0?loop=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this page , it worked for me:

http://www.labnol.org/internet/youtube-video-background/27933/

I hope it helped you.

Comment: as per [How to answer a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline

Comment: I could do it well, putting code in page and explain it, but the "system" to put the text in code mode doesn't works well.

Answer (score 0):

It will do the magic
`<video autoplay loop id="video"></video>
<script>
jQuery(window).bind("load", function($) {
    jQuery("video#video").append('<source class="hidden-xs" src="/assets/Video/code.mp4" type="video/mp4">')
});
</script>`